# How to rate symmetry

Tags: ratings

I'm designing an interface where the user needs to rate the symmetry of 2 objects.

The ratings are:

**1 means not symmetrical and 5 means very symmetrical.**

Currently, it has a star rating. However, the star icon suggests quality, and I don't want the user to think that a symmetric pair is better an asymmetric one.

How can I allow people to rate symmetry without relying on star-ratings?

Comment: Not to be a grammar a-hole, but isn't symmetry absolute? Either something is symmetrical or not, any degree of "almost-symmetrical" translates to non-symmetrical (?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try creating a set of icons - where the symmetrical icon would be a circle with a line halfway through (acting as a mirror).

Then gradually making the two sides less symmetrical, so offsetting the semi circles, and so on until you have a semi circle one side and a triangle on the other (or something that is equally not as symmetrical)

Equally if you can, I would suggest having 3 states, not symmetrical, some symmetry, and competently symmetrical. This may make it easier for users to define each state.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know perhaps such iconsets? I'd rather not reinvent the wheel

Comment: Unfortunately I think you would need to create something like this as its pretty specific

Answer (score 3):

Rather than a filled in series of symbols I'd suggest a scale using radio buttons or a slider which has symmetrical and one end and non symmetrical (or asymmetric) at the other. User then pick a point on that scale and only that part is marked.